# Domain registrar said I need to provide at least two of DNS servers

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

I'm trying to build a home server, like example.com should be bounded to my global ip 123.xx.xx.456 through my wifi router (tplink router) dynamic DNS setting.

But the problem is that on the domain registrar saying I need to provide at least two of DNS servers for some reason, but on the router setting it's only available for only one server e.g. myhostname.tplinkdns.com but not more than two e.g. myhostname.tplinkdns.com and myhostname02.tplinkdns.com

So, is there any way to workaround this issue?

Comment: The `tplinkdns.com` is a *dynamic DNS* service intended to give your IP address a public hostname. It is not intended for enabling you to host DNS servers, and dynamic IP addresses are not suitable for hosting DNS services, anyway. Some registrars provide basic DNS services for their domain owners. As this is a home server question, I'm voting to close it as off-topic.

Comment: Do you mean that I don't need to use the router's DDNS service but I just need to use the DNS service on the registrar to add an A record specified the router's public IP address? (sorry I thought I posted the post to superuser I misposted to this wrong place)

Comment: Yes. Or with a subdomain you could use a CNAME record, e.g. `home.example.com. CNAME yourhostname.tplinkdns.com.`

Comment: Hello @downvotors could you just request "close"? I don't think my question deserves this downvotes at all. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: `123.xx.xx.456`  is not an IP address.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: Try and tell that to the Hollywood. :)

Comment: @EsaJokinen Yes, but the difference is that Hollywood is entertainment where here it should be real life :-)

Comment: @pupsozeyde Regarding downvotes: "Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow."

Comment: As I said it's just misposting. I admit this post is not appreciated here, so I will kindly accept its closing. But the problem is that despite I said it's misposting, they just downvoted but not with requesting the close. I feel malicious intent from them to be honest.

Comment: "they just downvoted but not with requesting the close." How do you know? Right now there is explicitly 4 down votes and 4 close votes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to implement dynamic DNS server on your router. You can simply add A record on your domain registrar website to connect your domain with the public IP address.

Also note that you may need to wait two or more days to make sure your domain is available to your IP.